# calling method on enum

Tags: java, enums

```
public enum AgeGroup {
        CHILD{
           public int get(){
               return 10;
           } 
        }, 
        TEEN, YOUNG, MID, OLD;
    }
```

I have an enum `AgeGroup` and as you are seeing that `CHILD` has one method `get()`. Can somebody tell me why we can't call `get()` from `CHILD` what is the design approach behind this or why is it designed like this?

Comment: I have the same problem. I find it strange that is possible to define a method (only) on a specific enum, CHILD in your example, but there is no way to invoke it. I mean the code compiles but that method can't be called as less as you define a "default" method for the other enum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, all instances of an enum are of the *same type*, which means all instances have the *same set* of methods.

You need to declare a method on the enum type itself for instances to have a method:

```
public enum AgeGroup {
    CHILD{
       public int get(){
           return 10;
       } 
    }, 
    TEEN, YOUNG, MID, OLD;
    public int get() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

If all instances overrode the `get()` method as `CHILD` has, you could declare the method as `abstract`, which forces the coder to implement the method if new instances are added.

The best approach is to use a `final` field, initialized via a custom constructor, with a getter:

```
public enum AgeGroup {
    CHILD{10), TEEN(19), YOUNG(35), MID(50), OLD(80);
    private final int age;
    AgeGroup(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public int get() {
        return 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Javadoc says: "The enum declaration defines a class (called an enum type)."
So, basically you can include some methods into enum declaration, but the methods will be defined for all elements of the enum.
Check the Planet example here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html
What you have written doesn't qualify as a valid declaration of a class (or enum) because you try to declare a function for only one element of the enum.

Comment: Yeah, although it's not a valid declaration of enum, it compiles. Correct me if I am wrong but I think this is not logical, I mean the way that this behavior was implemented for the enum.